# How can I get current index through FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, routeparams

**I'm passing data to details screen with Navigation params, everything works correct, the only thing that I want to pass clicked current level index to `Object.entries[currentIndex]`, I'm not sure how  can I get that.**

```
<FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.index}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View>
              {item.sTask?.map((levels, i) => (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tasks', { item })}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#33333325',
                      paddingHorizontal: 20,
                      paddingVertical: 10,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      marginVertical: 20,
                      marginHorizontal: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text>{Level 1}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                   
                   <TouchableOpacity>
                     {Another level...}
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
          )}
        />
```

**Details screen:**

```
  const [currentTaskGroupIndex, setCurrentTaskGroupIndex] = useState(0); <---- We need to set current index somehow to current clicked index

  //Test item params data
  useEffect(() => {
    const mapData = item?.sTask?.map((tasks) => {
      return Object.entries(tasks)[currentTaskGroupIndex].map((level) => {
        // console.log(level);
      });
    });
  }, [item]);
```

**No matter which level i clicked, i'm getting Level 1 details**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like :

```
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tasks', { item:item, index:i })}
```

and then in details screen:

```
const indexParam = props?.route?.params?.index ?? 0

const [currentTaskGroupIndex, setCurrentTaskGroupIndex] = useState(indexParam); <---- We need to set current index somehow to current clicked index

  //Test item params data
  useEffect(() => {
    const mapData = item?.sTask?.map((tasks) => {
      return Object.entries(tasks)[currentTaskGroupIndex].map((level) => {
        // console.log(level);
      });
    });
  }, [item]);
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: index always returning 0

```
{"level1": [{"task1": [Array], "task2": [Array], "task3": [Array]}], "level2": [{"task1": [Array]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass index of the task in navigation param

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tasks', { item, index: i })}
```

Now, you no need map() to find your task

```
const mapData = item?.sTask[index]
```

you can pass your whole object in the navigation params

Comment: index always returning 0


{"level1": [{"task1": [Array], "task2": [Array], "task3": [Array]}], "level2": [{"task1": [Array]}]}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you answers, you were right, and plus i jusd added another Object.key().map and it worked

````
{item.sTask?.map((levels, i) => (
                <View key={i}>
                  {Object.keys(levels).map((key, i) => (
                    <View key={i}>
                      {console.log(key)}
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() =>
                          navigation.navigate('Tasks', { item: item, index: i })
                        }
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: '#33333325',
                          paddingHorizontal: 20,
                          paddingVertical: 10,
                          borderRadius: 10,
                          marginVertical: 20,
                          marginHorizontal: 20,
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text>{key}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  ))}
    ```
````